# How many Runnable's can be added to the queue in a fixed/cached Thread Pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, executor

Is there practically any limit on how many number of `Runnable`'s that can be added to the queue in a fixed/cached Thread Pool of say 10 worker Threads..??

In my application, I am trying to add 100000 `Runnable`'s.

```
for (int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
    executor.execute(new Task(i));
}
```

Will it actually process all the `Runnable`'s added to the Queue..? Or will it throw an `Exception`?

Comment: there is no single answer, it depends on how the executor is configured.

Comment: I suspect that among the limiting factors one will be the amount of RAM.

Comment: Or your JVM's max heap size.

Comment: It should process them until at least memory exhaustion. 100000 is not that big, but it depends on what those task do.

Comment: Although JVM heap space is the ultimate factor, in the OpenJDK, the number of Runnables in the queue cannot exceed Integer.MAX_INT.  For most practical applications, this wouldn't matter, but in some applications this hard limit is a factor as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maximum number of `Runnable`'s that can be added to the Queue in fixed/cached Thread Pool is decided by the memory allocated to the JVM.

Once all of the memory is consumed, JVM will throw

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

error message.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the [`java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#Executors) method, the limit is `Integer.MAX_INT`, at least in the OpenJDK implementation.

The OpenJDK 8 implementation of this method creates a new [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java#LinkedBlockingQueue), which defaults to a max size of `Integer.MAX_INT`.

Thus, the maximum number of `Runnables` in the default fixed thread pool is `Integer.MAX_INT`.  Note however, that if your heap is not large enough to store that many `Runnables`, then you will still be limited by the size of your heap.